# jQuery vertical accordion menu with toggle button and text link

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a standard vertical jquery accordion menu set up in a sidebar and it works fine. When you click on a link that contains a submenu, it expands and shows the submenu.

What I want to do is have list item expand the menu on click, but have the text link within the list item take you to a new page. I have seen examples in the past but am having a hard time finding an example now.

I have searched through SO for a while and have not found the answer anywhere. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML

```
<ul id="nav">
<li class="arrow"><a href="#">Level 1 Link</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2 Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2 Link</a></li>
        <li class="arrow"><a href="#">Level 2 Link (selected)</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Level 3 Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Level 3 Link</a></li>
                <li class="arrow"><a href="#">Level 3 Link (selected)</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Level 4 Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Level 4 Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Level 4 Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Level 4 Link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Level 1 Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Level 1 Link</a></li>
<li class="arrow"><a href="#">Level 1 Link (selected)</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2 Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2 Link</a></li>
        <li class="arrow"><a href="#">Level 2 Link (selected)</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Level 3 Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Level 3 Link</a></li>
                <li class="arrow"><a href="#">Level 3 Link (selected)</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Level 4 Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Level 4 Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Level 4 Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Level 4 Link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Level 1 Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Level 1 Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Level 1 Link</a></li>
```

jQuery

```
$('#nav > li.arrow').click(function(e){
 if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
   $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
   $(this).next().slideToggle();
   $('#nav li.arrow').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
 }
 e.preventDefault();
 });
 $('#nav > li > ul > li.arrow').click(function(e){
  if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
   $('#nav li ul li ul').slideUp();
   $(this).next().slideToggle();
   $('#nav li ul li.arrow').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
 }
 e.preventDefault();
 });
 $('#nav > li > ul > li > ul > li.arrow').click(function(e){
  if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
   $('#nav li ul li ul li ul').slideUp();
   $(this).next().slideToggle();
   $('#nav li ul li ul li.arrow').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
 }
 e.preventDefault();
 });
```